# Change image size when clicking on it in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

i wants to change an image size on clicking an image 
Here is my  Code

```js
function resizeImage(img) {
  var img = document.getElementsByClassName('image-slide');
  img.style.width = "500px";
  img.style.height = "500px";
  return img;
}
```

```html
<figure id="image-box">
  <img src="images/bicycle.jpg" alt="Bicycle image" style="width:100px;height:80px;" class="image-slide" onclick="resizeImage(this)">
  <img src="images/fantasy.jpg" alt="Fantasy image" style="width:100px;height:80px;" class="image-slide" onclick="resizeImage(this)">
  <img src="images/helicopter.jpg" alt="Helicopter image" style="width:100px;height:80px;" class="image-slide" onclick="resizeImage(this)">
  <img src="images/hot-choco.jpg" alt="Hot Chocolate image" style="width:100px;height:80px;" class="image-slide" onclick="resizeImage(this)">

</figure>
```

Actually i wants that if i click on an image it the javascript increase the size of this image i tried many javascript but nothing gain anything help me.

Comment: `var img = document.getElementsByClassName('image-slide');` returns a node array and redefines your `img` parameter, why not just use the parameter? (and why return the img?)

Comment: Note your solution changes the aspect ratio of your image (not square to square).

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss He wants to know how to increase image size .. his concern was not aspect ration ... so you could give him solution regarding this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply correct your code like this as you are already getting the needed element inside the function by using `this` :

```js
function resizeImage(img) {
  img.style.width = "500px";
  img.style.height = "500px";
}
```

```html
<figure id="image-box">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="Bicycle image" style="width:100px;height:80px;" class="image-slide" onclick="resizeImage(this)">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="Fantasy image" style="width:100px;height:80px;" class="image-slide" onclick="resizeImage(this)">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="Helicopter image" style="width:100px;height:80px;" class="image-slide" onclick="resizeImage(this)">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="Hot Chocolate image" style="width:100px;height:80px;" class="image-slide" onclick="resizeImage(this)">

</figure>
```

A more generic solution using jQuery if interested :

```js
$('.image-slide').click(function() {
 $(this).css('height',500);
 $(this).css('width',500);
})
```

```css
#image-box .image-slide {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure id="image-box">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="Bicycle image" class="image-slide">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="Fantasy image" class="image-slide">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="Helicopter image" class="image-slide">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="Hot Chocolate image" class="image-slide">

</figure>
```

Comment: Thank You So much i am just stuck on this Keyword You have solve my problem, Thank You Sooooo Much.Now i Understand it Perfectly and find the diffrence b/w id and class in javascript.Thank you again Brother.

Answer (score -1):

```
<figure id="image-box">
        <img src="images/bicycle.jpg" alt="Bicycle image"           width="100" height="80" class="image-slide"  onclick="resizeImage(this)"    >
        <img src="images/fantasy.jpg" alt="Fantasy image"           width="100" height="80" class="image-slide"  onclick="resizeImage(this)"    >
        <img src="images/helicopter.jpg" alt="Helicopter image"     width="100" height="80" class="image-slide"  onclick="resizeImage(this)"    >
        <img src="images/hot-choco.jpg" alt="Hot Chocolate image"   width="100" height="80" class="image-slide"  onclick="resizeImage(this)"    >

        </figure>

        Here is my JS

        function resizeImage(img)
        {

           img.width = parseInt(img.width) + 200;
           img.height = parseInt(img.height)+ 200;
        }
```

I have modified your code by just removing the line `var img = document.getElementsByClassName('image-slide');` 
and by modifying width and height attributes of img tag in dynamic way

Comment: The OP has a height of 500 in the example yet you set it to (effectively) 280 which is different.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I was just giving example ....so that he will know how to make it dynamic.. There is no point in finding such mistakes .If anyone helping out with right idea...